# how to pass a URL from one iframe to another iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe, query-string

I created a demo page where I had a text box on parent window where I input the URL and on click of a button the URL loads on the Iframe.. and it works!

Below is the Code for the same:

**HTML**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="display" src="http://jqueryui.com"></iframe>
<br>
<input type="text" id="url" value="http://jquery.com">
<button type="button" id="load">Load</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#load').click(function () {
        $('#display').attr('src', $('#url').val());
    });
});
```

**And here is the Fiddle for 1st Option (which is working): http://jsfiddle.net/Hs87s/**

**BUT** now the issue, I want to send the URL change request from one One **iframe** and load the URL in the Second Iframe.

All I did, added one new Frame and added button and text box in a different html and calling that html page in second iFrame. BUT this doesn't work.

below is the code for the second option:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    </script>
    <style>
        iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe id="display" src="http://jqueryui.com"></iframe>
    <br>
    <iframe id="inputURL" src="button.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Code for **button.html**:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#load').click(function () {
                    //alert("hi");
                    parent.$('#display').attr('src', $('#url').val());
                });
            });

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" id="url" value="http://jquery.com">
        <button type="button" id="load">Load</button>
    </body>
```

Can anybody please suggest how I can make the second option work?

Let me know if you need any other information.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The "button" frame can access any parent JS function by prepending "parent." in front of it, as long as they're on the same domain.

So the button frame would use:

```
parent.functionname();
```

....then the parent would contain that function.

EDIT:

Your click handler needs to be in the same page as your button, and you need to refer to the frame in the parent:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#load').click(function() {
        //alert("hi");
        parent.$('#display').attr('src', $('#url').val());
    });
});
```

Comment: May be I'm missing something as still not working... let me post my updated code in my question

Comment: jsfiddle.net is your friend.

Comment: Any idea what where I am making mistake??